# ogr2ogr: extract text elements from PDF into attributes

Tags: ogr2ogr, sqlite, geospatial-pdf

I have PDF created by the local geodetic authority which is kind of geospatial and contains layers of cadastre underground services (water, sewer, etc) as lines, points, and textual attributes describing elevations.

[image]

Here are the OGRINFO details:

```
INFO: Open of `report.pdf'
      using driver `PDF' successful.
Metadata:
  CREATION_DATE=D:20180607081101Z
  CREATOR=Esri ArcSOC 10.2.0.3370
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((573296.811062859 4797735.35436032,573297.174743531 4797926.39625182,573472.311327169 4797926.0737274,573472.76331659 4797735.04056676,573296.811062859 4797735.35436032))
...
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_34N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",21.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
...
```

I am using OSGeo4W Shell `GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20` and ogr2ogr command to convert PDF into SQLite:

```
ogr2ogr -a_srs EPSG:25834 -f sqlite sqlite\out.sqlite report.pdf
```

And the result in QGIS is OK except that textual elements are not transferred at all.

[image]

I even tried to use explicitly sql query with a hope that OGR - Feature Style Specification could extract those missing text as LABEL (this works with AutoCAD DXF files and textual objects in it):

```
-sql "select geometry, ogr_style from Layers_Points_WN_Anno"
```

but with no success. *ogr_style* is only filled with PEN definitions (even if this layer is full with text annotations).

[image]

Question is:

**Is it possible to transform somehow those text labels in PDF into some objects with OGR2OGR tool so they will show up in converted format ?**

Comment: Any chance of access to the file? Does the `Layers_Points_WN_Anno` have any more attributes?  Does `-sql "select * ....` or maybe `-sql "select geometry, * ...` help?

Comment: yeah, I only dont know what are possible ways to share it here and not violate some rules?

Comment: Sharing files via Dropbox, Box, or any other cloud file sharing doesn't violate any StackOverflow rules - but that assumes you are allowed to share it publically according to who supplied you the data....

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4e3k6rdy7xkdrgq/REPORT.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I have tried mentioned sql selects with no success.

Comment: Hmmmm no joy. Suspiciously if I load the PDF into Inkscape the numbers don't appear either, and I can't see them attached as attributes to the lines or points. Stuck.

Comment: Many GIS formats does not support text features, among others spatialite and shape. Texts are usually converted to points and you can create a label in QGIS to display the text. The text rotational angle sometimes not converted to an attribute, for example in the case of DXF file.